# Excel VBA - transpose formulas in vertical array to horizontal array

Tags: vba, excel

I have googled all sorts of phrases for an answer to my question but I'm having a hard time locating a solution that works.  It likely involves combination of a few different solutions, or a method I have yet to think of; so any help would be appreciated.

Say I have formulas in cells A1, A2, A3, and A4.  Let's say I want those EXACT formulas moved to the right one column.

In VBA I can say:

```
Range("B1:B4").Formula = Range("A1:A4").Formula
```

What I'm looking to do is something like this:

```
Range("B1:E1").Formula = Range("A1:A4").Formula
```

See how my B:E range is horizontal verses the vertical range of A1:A4.

I have tried all sorts of transpose options but I can't find any that work because I want the EXACT formula's to transfer.

Any thoughts?

Comment: So you are looking for a way to copy and paste transpose formulas, but keep the relative (not '=$A$1') references?

Comment: @seadoggie - actually exactly the opposite.  I need the copy/paste to keep the formulas as they are, but my plan is to then copy that row of formulas down to the bottom of my data using LastRow workarounds.

Comment: @J Taylor - If you don't care about relative references then you can copy and paste special. Select paste formulas and check the transpose option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try something like:

```
Sub PivotRangeFormulas()
    Dim rngSrc As Range: Set rngSrc = ActiveSheet.Range("A1:A4")
    Dim rngTgt As Range: Set rngTgt = ActiveSheet.Range("B1:E1")
    Dim i As Long: For i = 1 To rngSrc.Rows.Count
        Application.Index(rngTgt, i).Formula = Application.Index(rngSrc, i).Formula
    Next i
End Sub
```

You could also use an Offset function from the first cell in each range

Comment: I'm not a complete novice with VBA, but I'm also not a coder/developer (I do reporting and data analytics), so reading this and understanding it takes longer for me than it would for others.

That said, I think I see what you're doing here.  I'm not familiar with the application.index reference but I get the gist of it.

I'll give this a shot today/tomorrow and report back findings

Comment: So actually, this worked.  It is strange though that when I begin typing Application.Index I do not receive the help dialog box, leading me to believe Application.Index is not a valid function.  That said this worked perfectly.  Thanks so very much!

Answer (score 1):

```
Range("B1:E1").Formula = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:A4").Formula)
```

Answer (score 0):

Is locking the cell reference inside your formulas possible? I'm sure you are aware, but the F4 key (pc) will toggle referenced cell locks. The dollar sign locks the column letter or row number [A6, $A$6, A$6, $A6]. If you lock your cell references, you can then copy and transpose the formulas.

```
Range("B1:E1").Copy
Range("A1").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteAll, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks:= _
    False, Transpose:=True
```

Here is another option: Try recording a macro while entering your formula in the cell. If your formula is:

```
=SUM(D3:D4)
```

Depending on where you entered the formula, the VBA output might look like:

```
"=SUM(R[3]C:R[4]C)"
```

Here is the absolute reference in VBA:

```
"=SUM(R3C4:R4C4)"
```

You could then do something like:

```
Range("A8:A23").FormulaR1C1 = "=SUM(R3C4:R4C4)"
```

This will enter the formula =SUM($D$3:$D$4) in all the cells from "A8:A23". If you play with the brackets in the VBA formula, you should be able to make it work. The formula below searches the column to the left of the selected cell(s) containing the formula for the text "nff":

```
    Selection.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=SEARCH(""nff"",RC[-1])"
```

Comment: @Bo - yes it's possible, however the next step of my code will be to drag those formulas down to the bottom of my data so I need the references to be relative when they go in.

I suppose I could make them absolute, use the copy/paste transpose function, and then make them relative again in the new location through another line of VBA code...